# How to create an advanced search/filter using Google App Maker's Query Script?

Tags: google-app-maker

I'm making an app with an advanced search feature which can help users filter data from dropdowns and textboxes (Dropdown to choose column and clause, Textbox for entering search parameter) like this one:

**Advanced Search page sample:**
[image: Advanced Search page sample]

I tried to bind the Column's name dropdown to `@datasource.query.parameters.Parameter` and changed the Query part of the datasource like this:

**Datasource's Query Script and Parameters:**
[image: Datasource's Query Script and Parameters]

However, I keep getting errors like:

> Parameter 'Column' is used in 'where' clause but not defined in property 'parameters'

Could you please tell me how can I resolve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You literally have to construct your 'Where' clause in this case and then set the parameter of the where clause equal to your parameters. So lets say your first set of parameters is Column1: Name, Query1: contains, Parameter1: John, then your datasource needs to have the following parameters Column1, Query1, and Parameter1 and your bindings on your dropdown1, dropdown2, and textbox1 should be:

```
@datasource.query.parameters.Column1
@datasource.query.parameters.Query1
@datasource.query.parameters.Parameter1
```

respectively.

Then your query script needs to be as follows:

```
if (query.parameters.Field1 === null || query.parameters.Query1 === null) {
  throw new app.ManagedError('Cannot complete query without Parameters!');
}

switch (app.metadata.models.MaintenanceManagement.fields[query.parameters.Field1].type) {
  case 'Number':
    query.parameters.Parameter1 = Number(query.parameters.Parameter1);
    break;
  case 'Date':
    query.parameters.Parameter1 = new Date(query.parameters.Parameter1);
    break;
  case 'Boolean':
    if (query.parameters.Parameter1 === 'True' || query.parameters.Parameter1 === 'true') {
      query.parameters.Parameter1 = true;
    } else {
      query.parameters.Parameter1 = false;
    }
    break;
  default:
    query.parameters.Parameter1 = query.parameters.Parameter1;
}
query.where = query.parameters.Column1 + " " + query.parameters.Query1 + "? :Parameter1";
    return query.run();
```

So your where statement essentially becomes a string that reads 'Name contains? :Parameter1'  (i.e. John) that then becomes your query. Hope this makes sense, feel free to ask follow up questions.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I want to ask that what does `query.parameters.Param1 = query.parameters.Parameter1;` really do? I understood that  `query.parameters.Column1` represents dropdown1's value and `query.parameters.Query1` represents dropdown2's value but why the parameter is different from the other two? Do I need to add the Param1 to the datasource manually?  P/S: I got an error: _Unexpected input at '? :Param1'_ when I tried to execute the script.

Comment: @Kiko I just tested some sample code again and you do not need the second line of code. Just change the first line to :Parameter1 instead of :Param1 and you will be good to go. Not sure if that will resolve your error or not. I have edited my answer reflecting the updated code.

Comment: The code worked for String but if Parameter is a number, it got an error: ___Expected number for value of 'Parameter1' parameter___. Can we convert the `:Parameter1` to Number if the column requires Number type value?

Comment: @Kiko I have edited my answer once more to include some additional code to determine the field type of your column parameter. I tested the new code with a number in the textbox for Parameter1, however I have not tested Date or Boolean field, so for those types of fields you may need to do some additional testing. Hopefully this will get you going in the right direction. Also included an error return if Column1 or Query1 parameter is null, this should probably be important to include as well.

Comment: The code worked fine except the Exception part. When using `throw app.ManagedError` I got an error (Can't post here because it's very long and hard to understand but if you want I will Upload an image of it). So I changed to `throw new Error('error');` then it worked fine.