# Trying to filter a table datasource dynamically

Tags: google-apps-script, google-app-maker

Ultimately I want to filter based on values pulled from a form, but for now, hardcoding it, this isn't working. The tricky part is that which fields are being fitlered on is also dynamic:

m1 and m2 are the metadata fields, v1 and v2 are the value fields.

What I have is this:

```
function basicQuery (m1, m2, v1, v2){
  var results = [];
  var query = app.models.DATASOURCE.newQuery();
  query.filters.m1._contains = v1;
  query.filters.m2._contains = v2;
  return query.run();
}
```

This throws "TypeError: Cannot set property "_contains" of undefined to "Textvalue". But while v1 and v2 are being correctly recognized, m1 and m2 are not.I think what I need is something like

```
m1 = app.model.DATASOURCE.getField(m1);
```

None of the tutorials I watched were quite what I wanted, if someone can point me in the right direction I'd be thrilled.

I just need to dynamically filter my table.

(adding the handler function, although I don't think this is the problem):

```
function handleBasicQuery(){ 
  var m1 = "document_name";
  var v1 ="TextValue";
  var m2 = "Region";
  var v2 = "North America";
  console.log("--handleBasicQuery--");
  google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(
    function successHandler(expectedValue){
      console.Log (expectedValue);})
  .withFailureHandler(
    function failureHandler(){
      console.log("undefined");})
  .basicQuery(m1, m2, v1, v2);
}
```

Comment: Hi, J. G.! I think your issue is easier - to use computable property names you have to use bracket notation `query.filters[m1]._contains`. The error msg prompts that result of `filters.m1` is `undefined`, since there is no property `m1`

Comment: Thanks Oleg! Do you know how to plug the results into a table?

Comment: NP! Not that I am well-versed in App Maker, unfortunately... But judging from your code you use its `Model` class to to query records, right? Where would you like to save the results (do you mean the same `Model` or somewhere else?)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get Json specific variable data from Coinmarketcap API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56448428/get-json-specific-variable-data-from-coinmarketcap-api)

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54396214/how-to-create-an-advanced-search-filter-using-google-app-makers-query-script/54404774#54404774. The answer that I provided here has the potential to construct a dynamic where clause with multiple fields, filters such as equal/contains/in, and of course the query comparison. What I had not included in this is the possibility of also including the and/or operator. Either way this might give you some ideas how to get yours started.